# Sometimes my Android app views don't show up properly 

Tags: android, eclipse, nine-patch

I have noticed an issue regarding certain layout attributes and 9-patch drawables. Sometimes, it seems that they don't get 'compiled' with the rest of the code. I don't know much about the process by which 9-patch drawables are interpreted (I assume it does at compile time?) but  I assume there are metadata associated to them. If that is the case, let say those metadata are not taken into account. In such cases, what I usually do is to clean my project many times, or restart Eclipse or even... restart my computer.

I don't want to make bold assumptions on why this is happening (like memory issues on the IDE side), but do you guys have any explanations? Does it happen to you as well?

Note that it also applies to other view attributes like margins or paddings.

I have set the max heap space taken by Eclipse up to 1Gb and I have to say that even with that Eclipse crashes a lot. May be all these are related and can be put inside the hat of memory issues.

Thanks!

Comment: Why the question has been downvoted?

Comment: This happens to me too. It's really random and hard to reproduce, but I think it definitely is a compile time issue as you said.